# Scala function : What is the return type

Tags: scala, function, lambda

I'm trying to wrap my head around the following method signature.  I believe that logAccess is a function that takes two parameter lists, and returns a function whose return type is a LogEntry.

Or is the return type simply a `RouteResult` that is lazily evaluated.

```
def logAccess(remoteAddress: RemoteAddress, start: Long)(request: HttpRequest): RouteResult => Option[LogEntry] = {
   case RouteResult.Complete(result) =>
     val ip = remoteAddress.toOption.map(_.getHostAddress)
     val state = sisCache.get
     statsWriter.recordAccess(state, request.uri.toString, request.method.name, ip, result.status.intValue, time.ms - start)
     Some(LogEntry(s"state: $state, clientIP: $ip, uri: ${request.uri}, method: ${request.method.name}, status: ${result.status}, took: ${time.ms - start}ms", InfoLevel))
   case RouteResult.Rejected(rejections) =>
     None
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

logAccess is a function that accepts two parameter lists and returns a (RouteResult => Option[LogEntry]), that is, a function that takes a RouteResult and returns a Option[LogEntry].

The syntax "{ case whatever => ... } defines a partial function, which is an instance of PartialFunction, which is a subclass of Function, [as you can see in the documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/PartialFunction.html). Since this partial function accepts a RouteResult and returns an Option[LogEntry], it is a (RouteResult => Option[LogEntry]) and can be returned from logAccess.